# LeakCanary reports leaked activity Instance by anonymous implementation of locationlistener

Tags: android, memory-leaks, anonymous-inner-class, leakcanary

In onDestroy

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
locationListener = null;
```

The Anonymous implementation

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if (chatId != null) {
                        double radius = 6378.137;
                        double oldLat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                        double oldLng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                        double newLat = location.getLatitude();
                        double newLng = location.getLongitude();
                        double dLat = Math.toRadians(newLat - oldLat);
                        double dLng = Math.toRadians(newLng - oldLng);
                        double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(oldLat))
                                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(newLat)) * Math.sin(dLng / 2)
                                * Math.sin(dLng / 2);
                        double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                        double valueResult = radius * c;
                        double difInMeters = valueResult * 1000;

                        if (difInMeters > 2.0) {

                            pushLocation(location);

                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + status);
                    switch (status) {
                        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                            Log.d(TAG, "GPS.Available");
                            break;
                        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                            Log.d(TAG, "GPS.OutOfService");
                            break;
                        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                            Log.d(TAG, "GPS.TemporarilyUnavailable");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProviderdisabled: " + provider.toString());
                }
            };
```

LocationManager and LocationListener are imported from

```
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
```

I leave the Activity with the back button, so I tried overriding onBackPressed, and removing updates from the locationManager in onBackPressed, but I got the same Leak.

The following is the Logcat of the with the leak

```
D/LeakCanary: In findmyfriends:1.0:1.
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * findmyfriends.ScrollingMessengerActivity has leaked:
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.mListener
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * references findmyfriends.ScrollingMessengerActivity$6.this$0 (anonymous implementation of android.location.LocationListener)
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * leaks findmyfriends.ScrollingMessengerActivity instance
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 0.89 MB.
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: bead30b1-667e-45b1-8ccd-86a97abbfe43
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Device: samsung samsung SAMSUNG-SM-G891A poseidonlteuc
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 6.0.1 API: 23 LeakCanary: 1.4 6b04880
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5025ms, gc=173ms, heap dump=2093ms, analysis=34462ms
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Details:
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: * Instance of android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_STATUS_CHANGED = 2
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_DISABLED = 4
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_PROVIDER_ENABLED = 3
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   static TYPE_LOCATION_CHANGED = 1
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[32]@331418625 (0x13c10c01)
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   mListener = ScrollingMessengerActivity$6@324639008 (0x13599920)
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   mListenerHandler = android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1@322816704 (0x133dcac0)
09-26 18:28:13.367 25892-26857/findmyfriends D/LeakCanary: |   this$0 = android.location.LocationManager@322815648 (0x133dc6a0)
```

I previously discovered a memory leak with locationListener during onOrientationChange,

I solved it by placing

```
if (childListener != null) {
        mChatRef.removeEventListener(childListener);
        childListener = null;
    }
```

in onSaveInstanceState.  And run the initialization function with the anonymous implementation of locationListener.

Why isn't `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)` releasing the reference to the activity?  Any suggestions would be appreciated!  thanks in Advance!!

*Edit*
Ok, still haven't solved the MemoryLeak, but I removed the anonymous class and instead, I'm having the Activity implement LocationListener.

I'm still getting the same memory leak.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I seem to have the same one :(

Comment: I have the same problem, and i don't know why...

Comment: Where is the registration for location updates done in the activity?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need to use the onDestroy event, but rather onPause. When activity is destroyed, you don't need to worry since the listener will be killed and removed from memory, but onPause will be called when Activity goes into background.

In my case, the problem was that I wasn't removing the listener from onPause, and as a result it was continuing to get results from LocationManager.